# Return a unique row based on a single column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table (Employee).

**Employee**

```
ID   Name   Salary  Department
------------------------------
1    Steve  10000   SQ
2    Buck   15000   AS
3    Dan    10000   SQ
4    Dave   10000   AS
5    Jack   30000   AS
6    Amy    8000    GM
```

I need to return one employee per each department. For instance, for the above date I need to return the data as below:

```
ID   Name   Salary  Department
------------------------------
1    Steve  10000   SQ   ( I can either return Steve or Dan for this group SQ)
2    Buck   15000   AS   ( I can either return Buck or Dave or Jack for this group AS)
6    Amy    8000    GM
```

Comment: Why would you want to return a random employee?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a good use for `row_number()`:

```
select id, name, salary, department
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by department order by department) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
```

If you want the first or last id, use `order by id asc` or `order by id desc` in the `row_number()` partitioning clause.  If you want a random row, use `order by dbms_random.value`.